# Kiwi-TCMS manage.py migrate gets permission 13 error

Tags: kubernetes, kiwi-tcms, kiwi

Having trouble running the `manage.py migrate` command in our kubernetes cluster. It seems to have lost permission to run anything. None of the `manage.py` commands work, they all get the same issue.

I have no ability to change the permissions or ownership on the container. This worked in the past (at least Nov 2021) but using the latest version causes this error. Does anyone have any idea why the commands no longer work?

```
bash-4.4$ ./manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tcms/core/checks.py", line 15, in check_installation_id
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file_handle:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Kiwi/uploads/installation-id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add this to `deployment.yaml`:

```
securityContext:
   fsGroup: 1001
```

Comment: It's been a permission problem all along. It's likely that uploading attachments hasn't worked either b/c attached files are also stored under `/Kiwi/uploads`.